# Create Custom URLs

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

I have a model that returns a list of artist's names from a database along with their ID. I want to loop through these artists in my view and create links to their pages with the following format:

```
http://www.example.com/the-artist-name/artist-portfolio/ID.html
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller

```
$data['artists'] = $this->artists_model->get_all(); // should return array
$this->load->view('yourview', $data);
```

View

```
<?php foreach($artists as $artist): ?>
    <a href="http://example.com/<?php echo $artist['name']; ?>/artist-portfolio/<?php echo $artist['id']; ?>.html">
        <?php echo $artist['name']; ?>
    </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Do you know how to do this in the model? i.e. make the view cleaner?

Comment: Models make controllers cleaner. Controllers make views cleaner. Put your Database and validation rules in the model and prepare arrays in the controller and send them to the view. Loop over them inside the view. This is about as clean as a view will be.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the data from the model into the view and loop through it like you normally would.

In your controller:

```
$view_data['artists'] = $this->artist_model->get_artists();
$this->load->view('view.php', $view_data);
```

In your view:

```
foreach ($artists as $artist) {
    echo "<a href=\"http://www.example.com/{$artist['name']}/artist-portfolio/{$artist['id']}.html\">{$artist['name']}</a>";
}
```

Comment: Is codeigniter smart enough to load `view.php`? I have never included a file extension in my `view()` calls.

Comment: The file extension does not need to be specified unless you use something other than `.php`.